# What controls the minimum allowable browser viewport width?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am trying to get comfortable with responsive web design, using media queries to adapt my layout to the current size of the browser viewport. I have noticed that in both Google Chrome and in Firefox, when I drag the right-side border of my browser window to the left to make the viewport narrower, there is a point where I am no longer able to make it narrower.  This often prevents me from testing my media queries for the narrowest widths.  When this happens, I have found that the browser developer tools allow me to set the viewport width as narrow as I want. This isn't a significant problem for me, but it made me wonder what determines the narrowest width that a browser (either Firefox or Chrome) will allow you to resize the viewport to when not using the developer tools? Is this a browser setting?

If anyone can clear this up for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Paul